# How can i add a url image in my function for each switch case?

Tags: javascript, image, function

How can I add a url image in my function for each switch case? (so that the image displays inside the mybox div along with the text on button click)

```js
function tests() {

  let combo = document.getElementById("string_determine");
  let div = document.getElementById("mybox");
  let string_determine;

  switch (combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text) {
    case '"red" + "blue"':
      string_determine = "purple";
      div.style.color = "purple";
      break;
    case '"blue" + "green"':
      string_determine = "turquoise";
      div.style.color = "turquoise";
      break;
    case '"green" + "red"':
      string_determine = " brown";
      div.style.color = "brown";
      break;

    default:
      string_determine = "NONE";
  }
  console.log(string_determine);
  document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = string_determine;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="test.js"></script>

<select name="string_determine" id="string_determine">
  <option value=>Select Value</option>
  <option value='"red" + "blue"'>"red" + "blue"</option>
  <option value='"blue" + "green"'>"blue" + "green"</option>
  <option value='"green" + "red"'>"green" + "red"</option>

</select>

<button onclick="tests()">Yes</button>


<!-- this is the box -->
<div class="container">
  <h3> Selection </h3>
  <div id="mybox" class="box">
    <label for="mybox"> </label>
    <output name="mybox" type="text"><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set an img tag src property with javascript?

Comment: you could create 3 images named `purple.png`, `turquoise,png` and `brown.png`, and then assign a css style like `backgroundImage` via javascript: `div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + string_determine + '.png)'`

Comment: I'm just trying to use an image from the internet. One image for each switch case to accompany the string_determine string text. These should then be displayed together in the same div once the button is clicked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should help you.

Have a look at the following line:

```js
document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = 
    "<img src='" + IMAGE_SOURCE + string_determine + "'><p>" + string_determine + "</p>";
```

When running the code snippet below, you should wait a few seconds for the image to load from the internet.

```js
const IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100/?";
const IMAGE_EXTENSION = "";

// const IMAGE_SOURCE = "https://example.com/images/";
// const IMAGE_EXTENSION = ".png";

function tests() {
  let combo = document.getElementById("string_determine");
  let div = document.getElementById("mybox");
  let string_determine;

  switch (combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text) {
    case '"red" + "blue"':
      string_determine = "purple";
      div.style.color = "purple";
      break;
    case '"blue" + "green"':
      string_determine = "turquoise";
      div.style.color = "turquoise";
      break;
    case '"green" + "red"':
      string_determine = "brown";
      div.style.color = "brown";
      break;
    default:
      string_determine = "NONE";
  }

  let myBoxHTML = `<img src="${IMAGE_SOURCE}${string_determine}${IMAGE_EXTENSION}"><p>${string_determine}</p>`;
  console.log(myBoxHTML);
  document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = myBoxHTML;
}
```

```html
<select name="string_determine" id="string_determine">
  <option value=>Select Value</option>
  <option value='"red" + "blue"'>"red" + "blue"</option>
  <option value='"blue" + "green"'>"blue" + "green"</option>
  <option value='"green" + "red"'>"green" + "red"</option>
</select>

<button onclick="tests()">Yes</button>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Selection</h3>
  <div id="mybox" class="box">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add specific custom images instead of just one randomized image? (From 3 different image urls)